# Difference between header and cookie for cfhttpparam type

Tags: cookies, coldfusion, sharepoint-online, cfhttpparam

I am working on a ColdFusion app that authenticates to SharePoint Online and pulls some files using SharePoint's REST API as described in http://paulryan.com.au/2014/spo-remote-authentication-rest/

When I try to obtain the FormDigestValue by posting to _api/contextinfo if I set the `cfhttpparam` type to cookie I get a 403 forbidden, but if I pass the cookies as a header everything works but I don't understand why.

```
<cfhttpparam
    type="header"
    name="cookie"
    value="rtFa=#rtFa#;FedAuth=#FedAuth#"    
  />
```

Works but

```
<cfhttpparam
    type="cookie"
    name="rtFa"
    value="#rtFa#"    
/> 
<cfhttpparam
    type="cookie"
    name="FedAuth"
    value="#FedAuth#"    
/>
```

Fails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to see what is happening would be to inspect the traffic and *see* what is happening. Other than that, I know that the difference between using the `header` type and the `cookie` type for the `cfhttpparam` tag is URL encoding.

When you use the `header` type the value is **not** URL encoded.

When you use the `cookie` type the value **is** URL encoded.

So my guess would be that their API does not like when the value is URL encoded.

[Document reference for cfhttpparam attributes](https://cfdocs.org/cfhttpparam).